# ExceptionContext's IsChildAction

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

What is ExceptionContext's IsChildAction, when it is set? what is signifies?
please share some good articles or links about this.

Answer (score 0):

It indicates if an exception is thrown from a [child action](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/18/aspnetmvc2-render-action.aspx). If the exception occurs as part of the main action you may want to handle it differently than if the action is a child action.

Answer (score 0):

Look here 
[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controllercontext.ischildaction.aspx)

> Gets a value that indicates whether the associated action method is a child action.

And [here](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/18/aspnetmvc2-render-action.aspx/) for explanation about `child actions`